# Angular 4 checkbox pipe filter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hello I am trying to make a custom pipe filter which filters the data when checkbox is checked. I have a list of job locations which I want to filter when the certain job location is checked. I am providing the code which is related to the issue/problem.

Pipe code -

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'checkcity'
})
export class CheckcityPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(check: any, checked: any): any {
    let [loc] = checked;
    console.log('checked',checked);
    return checked
            ? check.filter(city => {return city.location }) 
            : check;
  }

}
```

Input Checkbox -

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" [(ngModel)]="checked" name="checked"> Bangalore
```

Data to filter -

```
<div *ngFor="let joblist of jobList | checkcity: checked">
    {{joblist.location}}
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting any error, share the log in that case.

Comment: What is `let [loc] = checked;` supposed to do`?

Comment: What does `return city.location` return? Is it supposed to filter all elements where `city.location` contains a value?

Comment: @Manu, hi I am not getting any error

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, hi I was experimenting, so you can remove that/ignore that, also I am not getting error, that is the problem

Comment: What error do you expect? What values to you expect to be shown? What is `city.location` supposed to contain?

Comment: Hi I have tried the below answer, maybe you can help with this @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename local var as `joblist` and the source as `jobLists` they should not be same. Can you try with the below code

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'checkcity'
})
export class CheckcityPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(check: any, checked: any): any {
    //let [loc] = checked;
    console.log('checked',checked);
    return checked
            ? check.filter(city =>  city.location == checked) 
            : check;
  }

}

<input type="checkbox" value="Bangalore" [(ngModel)]="checked" name="city"> Bangalore

<div *ngFor="let joblist of jobLists | checkcity: checked">
    {{joblist.location}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this, its not working and not giving me any error, but is saying that checklist undefined. I have put the list and checkbox filter in different component, will it affect.

Comment: @Akshay what is checklist? you have to import the pipe class in your list component class

Comment: it is better if you can put the code in separate files in the question for better understanding of others

Comment: sorry, it is checked undefined, I have imported the pipe class wherever required, else it would have given me an error. But there is no error coming.

Comment: @Akshay have you declared a property as `checked` in your component class? updated the name of checkbox.

Comment: Hello @Niladri, I moved my filter component to the list component, where the list of all location is displayed. It is working now, but when I am selecting a checkbox it is selecting all checkboxes -                                                                                           <form novalidate *ngFor="let joblists of jobList">
 <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="city" value="" [(ngModel)]="checked"> {{joblists.location}}
</form>

Comment: @Akshay that is because you have same `[(ngModel)]="checked"` for all the checkboxes so it's binding values to all

Comment: then whats the correct way of using [(ngModel)] instead of [(ngModel)]="checked". Please help

Comment: @Akshay create an array of values for joblists like `checked[ ] ` and use index of the ngFor to create ngModel like`<form novalidate *ngFor="let joblists of jobList;let index = index"> <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="city" value={{joblists.location}} [(ngModel)]="checked[index]"> {{joblists.location}} </form>`